# How to make \Rightarrow bold

Tags: arrows, bold

I tried doing, `\mathbf{\Rightarrow}`, but nothing happens.

How do I make the `\Rightarrow` symbol bold?

Comment: `\boldsymbol{\Rightarrow}`.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't look bold enough. Is there a way to make it stand out stronger?

Comment: Is it necessary that the bold arrow consists of two strokes? Otherwise packages like `pifont` provide a lot of different bold arrows.

Comment: Maybe using, only for this symbol, a font which is darker than Computer Modern, such as `fourier`.

Comment: @samcarter I would prefer if the arrow was just like \Rightarrow, with two strokes

Comment: @Bernard I'll have a look at fourier. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a way with which you can make any symbol fat: use the `contour` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Just the symbol:
\contour{black}{$\Rightarrow$}

\item The symbol between two bold symbols:
$\boldsymbol{A}\mathrel{\contour{black}{${\Rightarrow}$}}\boldsymbol{B}$

\item Using \texttt{contour} for everything:
\contour{black}{$A\Rightarrow B$}

\item \verb|\contourlength{0.02em}|:
\bgroup\contourlength{0.02em}\contour{black}{$A\Rightarrow B$}\egroup

\item \verb|\contourlength{0.01em}|:
\bgroup\contourlength{0.01em}\contour{black}{$A\Rightarrow B$}\egroup

\item Other symbols:
\contour{black}{$A\Leftarrow B=C\ne D$}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you would recreate the arrow in tikz, you could control how bold you like it by changing the `line width` to whatever value you like

```
\documentclass[border=6.662mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\myarrow}[1][0.1pt]{\tikz[baseline=-0.26em,y=3em, x=3em]{\filldraw[line width=#1] (0.4202,0.0021) .. controls (0.4202,-0.0000) and (0.4188,-0.0018) .. (0.4171,-0.0025) .. controls (0.3917,-0.0092) and (0.3699,-0.0236) .. (0.3509,-0.0401) .. controls (0.3355,-0.0538) and (0.3225,-0.0704) .. (0.3130,-0.0890) .. controls (0.3119,-0.0915) and (0.3094,-0.0929) .. (0.3066,-0.0929) .. controls (0.3028,-0.0929) and (0.2996,-0.0897) .. (0.2996,-0.0858) .. controls (0.2996,-0.0848) and (0.3000,-0.0837) .. (0.3003,-0.0827) .. controls (0.3087,-0.0665) and (0.3193,-0.0517) .. (0.3316,-0.0391) -- (0.1181,-0.0391) .. controls (0.1143,-0.0391) and (0.1111,-0.0359) .. (0.1111,-0.0320) .. controls (0.1111,-0.0282) and (0.1143,-0.0250) .. (0.1181,-0.0250) -- (0.3471,-0.0250) .. controls (0.3611,-0.0137) and (0.3766,-0.0046) .. (0.3935,0.0021) .. controls (0.3766,0.0088) and (0.3611,0.0179) .. (0.3471,0.0292) -- (0.1181,0.0292) .. controls (0.1143,0.0292) and (0.1111,0.0323) .. (0.1111,0.0362) .. controls (0.1111,0.0401) and (0.1143,0.0432) .. (0.1181,0.0432) -- (0.3316,0.0432) .. controls (0.3193,0.0559) and (0.3087,0.0707) .. (0.3003,0.0868) .. controls (0.3000,0.0879) and (0.2996,0.0889) .. (0.2996,0.0900) .. controls (0.2996,0.0939) and (0.3028,0.0970) .. (0.3066,0.0970) .. controls (0.3094,0.0970) and (0.3119,0.0956) .. (0.3130,0.0932) .. controls (0.3225,0.0745) and (0.3355,0.0580) .. (0.3509,0.0443) .. controls (0.3699,0.0278) and (0.3917,0.0133) .. (0.4171,0.0067) .. controls (0.4188,0.0059) and (0.4202,0.0042) .. (0.4202,0.0021) -- cycle;}}

\begin{document}

$\Rightarrow$ 
\myarrow\ 
\myarrow[0.25pt] 
\myarrow[0.5pt] 
\myarrow[0.75pt]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @marmot only picture mode ducks :)

Comment: @marmot And thanks for your comment about the dimensions!

Answer (score 3):

In the modern toolchain, with `unicode-math` and running either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can choose whatever font for bold math you want:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchUppercase }
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[version = bold]{XITS Math Bold}

\begin{document}
\(
 p \boldsymbol{\Rightarrow} q \Rightarrow r
\)
\end{document}
```

[image: bold math sample]

If you want all instances of `\Rightarrow` to be bold, you could select that one glyph from a font with a heavier weight:

```
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range = \Rightarrow]{XITS Math Bold}
```

In the legacy toolchain, you can load the `bm` package to get a better `\boldsymbol`, or (with some extra effort) you can import a glyph from your font of choice with `\DeclareMathSymbol`.